# Why does filter_input() not pick up arbitrary POST data?

Tags: php, forms, post

I noticed that when setting POST data programmatically, the PHP function `filter_input()` will not retrieve the data.

For example:

```
<?php
$_POST['test'] = 123;
$test = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'test');
var_dump($test);

// Output: null
?>
```

If `filter_input` retrieves the data from $_POST, and $_POST['test'] is a valid reference, why does it return null?

Comment: Because its origin wasn't provided by user input. You basically answered your own question.

Comment: Funny that I'm still clueless. Elaborate please.

Comment: It's self-explanatory. Have you gone through [**the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)? It specifically states *"One of INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, or INPUT_ENV"*, and then some. There's no mention of *programmatically*.

Comment: I understand that. If you noticed, I even included `INPUT_POST` in the example. If filter_input retrieves data from $_POST, and $_POST['test'] is a valid reference, why is it returning null?

Comment: @reformed Because it's from the code! You have to submit a form and send the request back! Then filter_input works!

Comment: `$var = $_POST['var'];` is user input, not as you have it, programmatically. It's returning NULL because of just that, "not input", so it null's out; invalid, false, not true. Is this for a test you're taking, a job interview? ;) Ask the guys at PHP.net for their reason/explication lol I'm just "reading the manual".

Comment: @Rizier123 I know it's from the code! I stated "programmatically" for a reason.

Comment: You can take it up with Brad now. He's got the "answer" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is the parsed POST body, turned into an array.  When you add a key to `$_POST`, you're adding it to the array **after** that POST body data has been parsed.

When you use `filter_input`, it's getting its data from the actual POST body, not from `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks. This was a helpful answer in understanding how filter_input works in relation to $_POST. Would you happen to know where the implementation of `filter_input` can be found?

Comment: @reformed https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3efc331701786d7ffd2587013d71a4dba0070759/ext/filter/filter.c#L706